# How to add "if no click" to a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATED**: I have a conditional statement that is dependant on the time a user clicks during a video playing. The result of their response is either too early, correct or too late and is displayed at the end of the video. How can I add in another result option for if the user doesn't click before the video ends? In this case, not clicking is a different response to clicking too late.

Currently I have working...

```
// get result based on time of click 
  $('#response').on('click', function() {
    var response-time = myVid.currentTime;
    var result;
if (response-time < 5) {
      result = "too early" ;
    } else if (response-time < 10) {
      result = "correct" ;
    } else {
      result = "too late" ;
  }
```

I tried adding console.log(result) to see if there is a null or undefined 'result' when there is no click before the video ends so I can maybe add another if statement based on the log response. But adding console.log interrupts the next on ended function because there is never a chance to log "result" if there is no click during the video.

I also tried an additional if statements using a variety of combinations for result being anything other than those listed above but with no success. This seems so logical to me but it doesn't work.

```
var finalResult
if (result != "too early" && result != "correct" && result != "too late") {
  finalResult = "you did not click"
}
```

I feel like I'm going round in circles with this one so any help is welcome

Comment: you can use video end event and find if user does not click it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a timeout that fires after 10 seconds that, if no click has occurred, runs the `too late` part and clears the click listener.

Also, when the click listener runs, clear the timeout:

```
$('#response').on('click', function() {
  var responseTime = myVid.currentTime;
  var result;
  if (responseTime < 5) {
    console.log("too early");
  } else {
    console.log("correct");
  }
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  console.log(result);
});
const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('too late');
  $('#response').off('click');
}, 10000);
```

If you don't want a hard-coded value during which clicks are listened for, and always want `too late` to come right when the video ends, then add a listener for the `ended` event instead of setting a timeout:

```
$('#response').on('click', function() {
  var responseTime = myVid.currentTime;
  var result;
  if (responseTime < 5) {
    console.log("too early");
  } else {
    console.log("correct");
  }
});
$('#response').on('ended', () => {
  console.log('too late');
  $('#response').off('click');
});
```

If you also need to differentiate between clicking too late and not cicking at all, add another condition to your `responseTime` check. Live demo:

```js
const myVid = $('video');
myVid[0].play();
let result;
$('#response').one('click', function() {
  var responseTime = myVid[0].currentTime;
  if (responseTime < 5) {
    result = "too early";
  } else if (responseTime < 8) {
    result = "correct";
  } else {
    result = 'too late';
  }
  myVid.off('ended');
  $('#response').prop('disabled', true);
});
myVid.one('ended', () => {
  console.log('no response');
  $('#response').off('click');
  $('#response').prop('disabled', true);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('End result:', result);
}, 12000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button id="response">response - click here</button></div>
<video controls width="300" height="300">
  <source src="https://i.temp.media/video/50-x-50-10.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Why not use the `ended` event listener?

Comment: I think the ended listener is where I'll try to implement it. Currently i have on ended the `<div><h2>id="result"></h2></div>` is shown. If there is no click the h2 remains empty. Perhaps I can include an additional `if ($('#result').is(':empty')){
  //then "you did not respond" or something like that  }`  I might play around with that and see what I can implement.

Comment: If I change `var result = "no response"` I get the required result as the `if` statement overrides its value when appropriate which solves my initial problem. I added `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "no response" ;` to my replay video function so the default "result" is always "no response" unless there is a click response. Not sure if this is scalable but it works for now.

Comment: I updated my question with some additional information as the on ended option didn't solve my problem. I'm new here and assumed that was the correct thing to do

Comment: @RichardR `console.log`, by itself, cannot interrupt anything - aside from the console output, it's pure. If you want set the result to a variable, then do that: `$('#response').on('ended', () => { result = 'too late';` and then make sure to reassign `result` to `undefined` (or `null` or something) when the next video starts.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your advice, your solution is assuming that if the user "does not click" then the result should be "too late". As I updated in my question, clicking after a predetermined time during the video and not clicking during the video are 2 separate results. One is a "late response" and one is "no response" This is why I unaccepted your original solution

Comment: See snippet in answer for a live demo